# Equation of the ellipse for musical notation (the quarter note/crotchet and shorter)

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, music-theory

Note heads are often represented with a slightly rotated ellipse, as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_note) for instance (first image). Does anyone happen to know the equation of the ellipsis, and the rotation that's applied to it ? The only thing I thought about was trying to bruteforce it until I get something that looks alike.

PS : I hesitated between this website and SO. Yet, even if it's for programming purposes, it would have been off-topic on SO because the problem is not the development part, but rather the mathematical one.

Comment: This may be of interest to you: http://faculty.washington.edu/garmar/notehead_specs.pdf

Comment: Great document, thank you

Comment: The particular note head:

`    <path
       style="fill-rule:nonzero"
       d="m 18.3256,-11.4413 c -4.4487,0 -8.61244,1.62868 -12.49141,4.88596 C 1.95522,-3.29805 0.0157347,0.203527 0.0157396,3.9494 0.0157371,6.2295 0.856632,8.06172 2.53843,9.44607 c 1.68179,1.38433 3.87896,2.07653 6.59153,2.07653 4.44864,0 8.61234,-1.62866 12.49134,-4.88594 3.879,-3.25728 5.8185,-6.758861 5.8185,-10.50474 0,-2.2801 -0.8409,-4.11232 -2.5227,-5.49666 -1.6818,-1.38436 -3.879,-2.07656 -6.5915,-2.07656"
       vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />`

which is then only scaled and translated, not rotated.

Comment: "Ellipse" is a singular noun whose plural is "ellipses", and "ellipsis" is a singular noun whose plural is spelled the same way as the plural of "ellipse" but pronounced differently.  I wonder if you meant "ellipses" where you wrote "ellipsis". ${}\qquad{}$